# Load collections with existing ChildIds using explicit loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to explicit reload using existing Child Ids something like functionality of `Reload()` in `DbEntityEntry`? See also comments in code.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var parent = new Parent()
    {
        ParentId = 1,
        Childs = new List<Child>()
        {
            new Child()
            {
                ChildId = 2,
                ParentId = 1
            }
        }
    };

    context.Parents.Attach(parent);
    context.Entry(parent)
        .Collection(b => b.Childs) // Load only Employee with employee id of 2
        .Query()
        .Load(); //Is it possible to Reload only ChildId = 2?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, after `Query` method you can apply filters to the related entities you want to load:

```
 context.Entry(parent)
        .Collection(b => b.Childs) // Load only Employee with employee id of 2
        .Query()
        .Where(e=>e.ChildId==2)
        .Load();
```

Comment: Is it possible to load it without `Where` method?

Comment: Nope, that's what do the trick ;). The where condition is what filter the related entities.